# Programmatically insert text, headers and lists with R markdown

Tags: r, markdown

When using R markdown if one wants to add text using code there are some simple ways to do it.

This is also true for tables, using the `kable` command is very easy.

However, imagine you want to programmatically insert headers or lists to your report.

````
```{r, results='asis'}
headers=list("We","are","your","friends")
for (i in list_a){
    #add i as header
}
```
````

and you want this to be the same as writing in your Rmd file:

```
#We
#are
#your
#friends
```

Another example would be to automatically create headers instead of lists:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
list_a=list("We","are","your","friends")
for (i in list_a){
    #print i to a rmd list
}
```
````

as before this should have the same result as writing:

```
*We
*are
*your
*friends
```

**This is not only a formatting problem as the table of context for Rmd files is created dynamically according to these headers.**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to construct your wanted markdown in R and use that together with the argument `results = 'asis'` in your chunk options. Hence, something like the following will do what you want:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
headers <- list("We","are","your","friends")
for (i in headers){
  cat("#", i, "\n")
}
```
````

The `for`-loop here will create the output

```
# We 
# are 
# your 
# friends
```

which is used directly as input in the .md document.

Comment: Should there be any specific problem about using this after a plot? If I do something like:
`for (i in 1:2){
      cat("#",names(data)[i],"\n");
      nona_data = data[i][is.na(data[i])==F];
      vioplot(nona_data, col="gold");
      hist(nona_data,xlab="Small Particles", main=names(data)[i]) ;}`
The first header works, but not the second.

Comment: Yes, that may be a problem and may not work. The `results == 'asis'` is usually for text-output and is probably not compatible with the output of when plotting. However, I'm not quite sure. Anyway, it should be easy to split the chunk up into two (one for the plots and one for the text).

Comment: The order is important in this task as a new header is needed for each plot, how would you split the chunk?

Answer (score 8):

Use the [pander package](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/), which transform R objects into Pandoc's markdown:

```
> headers=list("We","are","your","friends")
> list_a=list("We","are","your","friends")
> library(pander)
> pandoc.header(headers)

# We

# are

# your

# friends
> pander(list_a)


  * We
  * are
  * your
  * friends

<!-- end of list -->
```

The first example used a [helper function](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#helper-functions) to create the headers, while the second demo simply called the [generic S3 method](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#generic-pander-method), that can robustly transform a variety of R objects into markdown.

Comment: I use this for loops where each iteration generates a loop, then a plot.  I found that I had to include a `cat("\n")` statement after printing my plot or any headers after the first iteration were rendered as text instead of markdown.

Answer (score 1):

For people who want plots below each header, this is how I do it.

````
```{r, results="asis"}

for (i in headers){
      cat("# ", i, "\n",
          knitr::knit_child("plot.Rmd", quiet = TRUE), "\n")
    }

```
````

In the `plot.Rmd` put your plot code in it, e.g.

````
```{r}
# plotting code
```
````

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me, compiling .Rmd to PDF in R 3.6.3:

````
```{r plot_loop_chunk, results='asis', tidy=FALSE}

for(i in 1:10){
    cat("#", "Header", i, "\n")

    print(<some loop-dependent plot>)

    cat("\n")
    cat("\n")
}

```
````