# Programmatically insert header and plot in same code chunk with R markdown using results='asis'

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, knitr, r-markdown

The `results = 'asis'` chunk option within Rmarkdown allows one to easily dynamically create text including headers.  However, I wish to dynamically create a header with the `asis` option, but then in the same code chunk insert some graphics.

The most related answer I could find for this is here: [Programmatically insert text, headers and lists with R markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588350/programmatically-insert-text-headers-and-lists-with-r-markdown), but the answer to this question does not allow both dynamic headers and plots within those dynamic headers.

Here is a simple reproducible example follows demonstrating what I can and cannot achieve with `results = 'asis'`

The code directly below does what I would expect, creating a header for each Species.

````
---
output: html_document
---
```{r echo = FALSE, results ='asis'}
for(Species in levels(iris$Species)){
  cat('#', Species, '\n')
}
```
````

The code directly below here does not do what I would like.  Ideally, the code directly below would generate a header for each Species with a plot underneath each header.  Instead, it generates the single `setosa` header in the output file followed by the three plots.

````
---
output: html_document
---
```{r echo = FALSE, results ='asis'}
library(ggplot2)
for(Species in levels(iris$Species)){
  cat('#', Species, '\n')
  p <- ggplot(iris[iris$Species == Species,], aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point()
  print(p)
}
```
````

Is there some way to dynamically generate the 3 headers with a plot under each header?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to add some new lines after the plots and before the headers, using `cat('\n')`:

````
```{r echo = FALSE, results ='asis'}
library(ggplot2)
for(Species in levels(iris$Species)){
  cat('\n#', Species, '\n')
  p <- ggplot(iris[iris$Species == Species,], aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point()
  print(p)
  cat('\n')
}
````

Comment: this does not seem to work with `grid.draw`. No matter how many `\n` I `cat`, the header still gets printed after the plot, even if I call `cat` in the R code before I call `grid.draw`

Comment: I am having the same problem you describe (and the fact that this answer is marked as a correct answer prevents other people from trying to solve this)

Comment: I managed to get it working with the following code after the plot: `cat('<br>') cat('\n')
cat('\n')`.