# Programmatically create tab and plot in markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, purrr, r-highcharter

I'm trying to create a dynamic number of tabs in my `rmd` with some content inside.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752095/programmatically-insert-header-and-plot-in-same-code-chunk-with-r-markdown-using) one doesn't help.
Something like this:

````
---
title: "1"
output: html_document
---

```{r }
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
      dplyr::group_split(Species) %>% 
      purrr::map(.,~{
        # create tabset for each group 
        ..1 %>% 
          hchart("scatter", hcaes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))
        })
```
````

Comment: Is that `highcharter::hchart`? Please be clear with non-base packages (`dplyr` too, safe to infer based on `purrr`?).

Comment: @r2evans yes. sorry for that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `results = 'asis'` knitr option to generate the tabs in the map function using `cat`.

Getting `Highcharter` to work with `asis` was trickier :

- `Highchart` **needs to be called once** before the `asis` chunck, probably to initialize properly, hence the first empty chart.
- to print the chart in the `asis` chunck, the HTML output is sent in `character` format to `cat`

Try this:

````
---
title: "Test tabs"
output: html_document
---

`r knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, cache = F)`

```{r}
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
# This empty chart is necessary to initialize Highcharter in the tabs
highchart(height = 1)
```


```{r, results = 'asis'}
cat('## Tabs panel {.tabset}   \n')
invisible(
  iris %>% 
      dplyr::group_split(Species) %>% 
      purrr::imap(.,~{
        # create tabset for each group 
        cat('### Tab',.y,'   \n')
        cat('\n')
        p <- hchart(.x,"scatter", hcaes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))
        cat(as.character(htmltools::tagList(p)))
      })
)
```
````

[image]

Note that while this solution works well, it goes [beyond the original use for `asis`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63644305/13513328)

Comment: thx a lot!  `highchart(height = 1)` and `tagList` were  good advice!

Comment: Works for .Rmd - as in the question - however the tabs do not appear in quarto