# Leaflet not rendering in dynamically generated R markdown html knitr

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, r-markdown

I've created a R markdown report where the sections and tabsets are dynamically created.

I have an issue where the Leaflet maps are not being generated in the output, but rather a blank white space. They do however render in R studio.

Here is an image showing how the output currently looks, and how it should look.

[image: Text]

Here is the code i've tried:

```
{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis', warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

for (estates in filtered_list){
map_data <- x_estates %>% filter(Street_Postcode == estates)

    cat("###", estates, "{.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}", "\n")
    cat("\n\n\n")
    cat("This is where the map will go ")
    
# generate leaflet plot (doesn't even show white space if not stored in tagList)
    page <- tagList(
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(map_data$Longitude, map_data$Latitude)
)

### options i've tried for getting the Leaflet map to plot correctly
   
page
print(page)
print(page[[1]])
page[[1]]
 
print(
 tagList(
     page[[1]]
    ))
 
 print(
    tagList(
     page
    ))
### end 

        cat("\n\n\n")
    

     for (major in Major$Titles) {
     
         cat("####", major, "\n")
         cat("\n\n\n") 
         
##### 
rest of code
#####

}
}
```

It has something to do with html rendering I presume, as static plots i've generated using ggmap work; however I want my maps to be interactive.

N.B. The maps render fine in R studio, just not in the knitr html output.

**EDIT**

As suggested by Susan Switzer, I have made some changes to the code. The leaflet plots now show (with interactivity too). Can alter the code to dynamically name and load the correct HTML file.

[image: Text]

```
    m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
addMarkers(map_data$Longitude, map_data$Latitude)
library(mapview)
m <- mapshot(m, url = paste0(getwd(), "/map.html"))
# m <- htmltools::includeHTML("map.html") produces an odd output where the entire document becomes a laggy leaflet map
# print(m) 

m <- htmltools::tags$iframe(title = "Map", src = "map.html")
print(m)
```

**EDIT 2**

Waldi has solved the issue when using points. However the same problem occurs when using clusters or heatmaps. e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
leaflet()
```

Minimal code to show examples with 3 sets of coordinates

```
long <- as.numeric(c("0.005638", "0.005648", "0.005658"))
lat <- as.numeric(c("51.62879", "51.62889", "51.62879"))
data1 <- data.frame(long, lat)


filtered_list <- 1:3
cat("## Tabs {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}", "\n")
for (estates in filtered_list){
    cat("###", estates, "\n")
    cat("\n\n\n")
    cat("This is where the map will go ")
    
        cat("1 ")
# generate leaflet plot (doesn't even show white space if not stored in tagList)
    page <- htmltools::tagList(
         leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
            addMarkers(lng=data1$long, lat=data1$lat, popup="The birthplace of R")
    )
    cat(as.character(page))
    
            cat("2 ")
    page <- htmltools::tagList(
         leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
            addMarkers(lng=data1$long, lat=data1$lat, popup="The birthplace of R", clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) 
    )
    cat(as.character(page))
    
    
        
            cat("3 ")
    page <- htmltools::tagList(
         leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
           addMarkers(lng=data1$long, lat=data1$lat, popup="The birthplace of R") %>% 
           addHeatmap(
    lng = data1$lat, lat = data1$long,
    blur = 20, max = 5, radius = 40
    )
    )
    cat(as.character(page))
    
    
        
            cat("4 ")
    page <- htmltools::tagList(
         leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
           addMarkers(lng=data1$long, lat=data1$lat, popup="The birthplace of R") %>% 
           addHeatmap(
    lng = data1$lat, lat = data1$long,
    blur = 20, max = 5, radius = 40
    )
    )
    cat(as.character(page))
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked into the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336898/how-to-save-leaflet-in-r-map-as-png-or-jpg-file? I think the use of mapshot or webshot is relevant here.

Comment: I think that will fix the issue. I've attempted it and made some progress. The leaflet maps are now displaying interactively, although all the same plot. Presumably as I am overwriting the map html. Will explore this further. https://i.imgur.com/8nKwuRA.png. I've updated the code above to show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a similar problem as described [here with Highcharter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63437006/13513328)

Try:

````
---
title: "Test Leaflet Tabs"
output: html_document
---

`r knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, cache = F)`

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
leaflet()
```

```{r,results='asis'}

filtered_list <- 1:3
cat("## Tabs {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}", "\n")
for (estates in filtered_list){
    cat("###", estates, "\n")
    cat("\n\n\n")
    cat("This is where the map will go ")
    
# generate leaflet plot (doesn't even show white space if not stored in tagList)
    page <- htmltools::tagList(
         leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
            addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
    )
    cat(as.character(page))
    }
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I did attempt that and experienced the same white box unfortunately. It renders as white space, despite "appearing" when inspecting the element: https://i.imgur.com/EOp5w7H.png

Comment: Did you run leaflet() once in the init chunck ?  The example shared works on my system (Win 10/R 4.0.2)

Comment: Markdown copy on StackOveflow is tricky : I edited my answer because backticks disappeared on the first attempt, should be working better,

Comment: I copied your code into a new document and it worked. I then pasted in my code, part by part to ensure it still works, and now it does. I don't know what aspect of your code fixed my problem, perhaps it was indeed the leaflet() in the init chunk. Thank you so much, I spent like 6 hours yesterday scratching my head at this.

Comment: My link to [Highcharter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63437006/13513328) was wrong, you can read here the explaination

Comment: Would you know why this fix works for points, but when introducing clusters or heatmaps it does not generate? Works fine in R studio, but doesn't when knitted. I've edited my question to include a reproducible example @Waldi  Thank you

Comment: @Jonathan West, I tried your second edit and don't know exactly why it doesn't work. However, I had a [discussion on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63644305/13513328) with knitr team, and they warned about unexpected effects when pushing `asis` to its limits.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that was solved by putting the leaflet into a widget frame.

```
l <- leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(map_data$Longitude, map_data$Latitude)

widgetframe::frameWidget(l, width = "100%")
```

This has the effect of saving html tiles for use in rendering. I'm pretty sure it just wraps the leaflet in a HMTL tag.

Comment: Just ran into this issue again and the accepted answer works for rendering from R Studio locally. But if you are displaying the Rmarkdown through Shiny Server, you will need to use the `widgetframe` solution.

Comment: After hours of searching for an answer, this solution works with vignettes - both leaflet and tmap. For tmap output, widgetframe::frameWidget(tmap_leaflet(map_1), width = "100%") works perfectly (just in case someone else has the same issue!)