# Leaflet does not display in a loop and conditional

Tags: r, r-leaflet

Trying to generate multiple plots and titles sequentially through a loop in an Rmarkdown document. This is the Rmd code.

````
---
title: "Leaflet"
output: html_document
---

```{r,eval=TRUE,include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

dfr <- data.frame(lat=c(51.517,48.859,50.850),lon=c(-0.074,2.294,4.346),label=c("London","Paris","Brussels"))
```

# As loop

```{r,echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE,results="markup"}
for(i in seq_along(dfr)){
    dfr1 <- dfr[i,,drop=FALSE]
    knitr::asis_output(paste0("## ",dfr1$label,"\n"))
    leaflet(height=450,width="auto") %>%
      addTiles(urlTemplate='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png') %>%
      addAwesomeMarkers(lat=dfr1$lat, lng=dfr1$lon, label=dfr1$label) %>%
      setView(lat=dfr1$lat, lng=dfr1$lon, zoom=10)
}
```

# Individually

```{r,echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE,results="markup"}
dfr1 <- dfr[1,,drop=FALSE]
knitr::asis_output(paste0("## ",dfr1$label,"\n"))
leaflet(height=450,width="auto") %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png') %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(lat=dfr1$lat, lng=dfr1$lon, label=dfr1$label) %>%
  setView(lat=dfr1$lat, lng=dfr1$lon, zoom=10)
```

```{r,echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE,results="markup"}
dfr1 <- dfr[2,,drop=FALSE]
knitr::asis_output(paste0("## ",dfr1$label,"\n"))
leaflet(height=450,width="auto") %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png') %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(lat=dfr1$lat, lng=dfr1$lon, label=dfr1$label) %>%
  setView(lat=dfr1$lat, lng=dfr1$lon, zoom=10)
```
````

This is the output.

[image]

When run as a loop, it does not display. It works when plotting individually.
I am not saving the plots as a list since I have other stuff to print per iteration, for example, the H2 heading as in the above example.

Another example using if.

````
---
title: "Leaflet"
output: html_document
---

```{r,eval=TRUE,include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

dfr <- data.frame(lat=c(51.517,48.859,50.850),lon=c(-0.074,2.294,4.346),label=c("London","Paris","Brussels"))

```

# If

```{r,echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE,results="asis"}
if("London" %in% dfr$label){
  dfr1 <- dfr[dfr$label %in% "London",,drop=FALSE]
  cat(paste0("## ",dfr1$label,"\n"))
  w <- htmltools::tagList(leaflet(height=450,width="auto") %>%
    addTiles(urlTemplate='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png') %>%
    addAwesomeMarkers(lat=dfr1$lat, lng=dfr1$lon, label=dfr1$label) %>%
    setView(lat=dfr1$lat, lng=dfr1$lon, zoom=10))
  cat(as.character(w))
}
```
````

```
R 4.1.0
leaflet 2.1.1
```

Comment: Perhaps [Leaflet not rendering in dynamically generated R markdown html knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63495178/leaflet-not-rendering-in-dynamically-generated-r-markdown-html-knitr/63495651#63495651) or [Printing any number of dataframes stored in list as paged tables in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63532652/printing-any-number-of-dataframes-stored-in-list-as-paged-tables-in-rmarkdown/63533860#63533860) help to answer your question.

Comment: I can confirm that the solution in this one works: [Leaflet not rendering in dynamically generated R markdown html knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63495178/leaflet-not-rendering-in-dynamically-generated-r-markdown-html-knitr/63495651#63495651)