# Putting tables automatically in tabs in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, tabs, r-markdown, knitr

I want to put tables produced from a `for()` loop in different tabs automatically. I used the code below from [similar code for plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752095/programmatically-insert-header-and-plot-in-same-code-chunk-with-r-markdown-using)

but it doesn't work properly for tables. It creates the tabs but doesn't show the tables in them. Could anyone please correct my code?

````
---
output: html_document
---

# title 1 {.tabset}
There should be one table in each tab. 

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}
for(Species in levels(iris$Species)){
  cat('\n##', Species, '\n')
  p <- iris[iris$Species == Species,]
  knitr::kable(p)
  cat('\n')
}
```
````

[image: The image shows my output; No table!]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `print` your tables within the `for` loop:

````
---
output: html_document
---

# title 1 {.tabset}
There should be one table in each tab. 

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}
for(Species in levels(iris$Species)){
  cat('\n##', Species, '\n')
  p <- iris[iris$Species == Species,]
  print(knitr::kable(p))
  cat('\n')
}
```
````

[image]