# programmatically insert header into multisection r markdown document

Tags: r, header, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I am creating a multi-section PDF document using R markdown, knitr, and pander. Though I have read previous posts [blog]: [Programmatically insert text, headers and lists with R markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588350/programmatically-insert-text-headers-and-lists-with-r-markdown/) "posts" on this topic, I am still encountering problems.

The function I'm using to insert headers is:

I can only provide a skeletal version of the code, which is actually several hundred lines long:

```
{r , echo=FALSE, include = TRUE, warning = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
    prt.scale.heading <- function(scale, iter) {
       txt <- "Analysis of "
       # add blank lines as suggested in previous post     
      cat("\n\n") 
      hdr <- paste(txt,scale,"Iteration",iter)
      # show header using the R markdown '#' symbol
       cat('\n#',hdr,'\n')
    }

do_analysis <- function(resp.data, scale, maxChanges = 1, 
                    filename = NULL)  {

    iter <- 0
    while (iter <= maxChanges) {
        prt.scale.heading(scale, iter)
        iter <- iter + 1
    }
}

do_analysis(resp.data = temp, scale.name, maxChanges = 5)
}
```

When I run my code, instead of seeing formatted section headers, I see the heading in plain text preceded by '#'. Note that all of the text, plots and tables (pander) are placed in one large chunk, and I set the chunk option results = 'asis' (as suggested in a previous post).

Suggestions?

Comment: Please show a short example of how you are using this in a chunk. A short, fully reproducible document would be even better.

Comment: I can only provide a skeletal version of the code, which is actually several hundred lines long:

Comment: Perfect! That's why I used *"short"* twice in my request. We really like **minimal** examples here. If you can demonstrate the problem in less than 20 lines it's great - much easier to debug.

Comment: I can only provide a skeletal version of the code, which is actually several hundred lines long:    

    ```{r , echo=FALSE, include = TRUE, warning = FALSE, results = 'asis'}


     do_analysis <- function(resp.data, scale, maxChanges = 1, 
      filename = NULL)  {
  
      iter <- 0
      while (iter <= maxChanges) {
       prt.scale.heading(scale, iter)
       iter <- iter + 1
      }
     }

     do_analysis(resp.data = temp, scale.name, maxChanges = 5)
    ```
     }

Comment: ```{r , echo=FALSE, include = TRUE,  results = 'asis'}
     do_analysis <- function(resp.data, scale, maxChanges = 1, 
      filename = NULL)  {
  
      iter <- 0
      while (iter <= maxChanges) {
       prt.scale.heading(scale, iter)
       iter <- iter + 1
      }
     }

     do_analysis(resp.data = temp, scale.name, maxChanges = 5)
    ```
     }

Comment: You'll make it much easier for us to help you if you paste into the body of your question a complete rmarkdown document that includes the code chunk in your comment and any other code necessary to create a complete, self-contained example that sets up all the important components of your issue and that we can work from to find a solution.

Comment: And do please edit it into your question - it's difficult to read multiline code in comments.

Comment: Edits are looking better - but please make sure it's copy/paste/run-able. I pasted the code you posted into a fresh RMD document and I can't run it because `scale.name` and `temp` aren't defined.

Comment: I added the code to the original post

Comment: Please provide sample values fro `temp` and `scale.name` so it is runnable.

Comment: I have been trying to create a simple example of the issue. Unfortunately, the simple example does not reproduce the error.